# (C++) Getting the error: invalid use of class::function and I have not the slightest clue why

Tags: c++

I was taking a course on C++ on this website called Udemy. I had just gotten finished with a video lecture on Classes. I decided to experiment around with the idea of using classes and header files, as is encouraged by the teacher. I began by creating 2 .cpp files and 1 header file. I created a function in the second .cpp file, then created a class for it in the header file, and tried calling it in the first .cpp file, but got the error in the first .cpp file: invalid use of 'Learn2::Learn2'. This is the first .cpp file:

```
    #include "Learn1.h"
    #include "Learn2.cpp"

    Learn2 learn2;

    int main() {

        string input;

        cout << "Would you like to see the menu of processes? (yes/no)" << endl;

        cin >> input;

        if (input == "yes"){
            showMenu();
        }
        else{
            cout << "all done here" << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    void showMenu(){
        cout << "Processes: " << flush;
        cout << " Quit(4)   Edit(5)" << endl;
        int input;

        cin >> input;

        switch(input) {
        case 4:
            cout << "You selected: quit(4)" << endl;
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << "You selected: edit(5)" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "not recognized" << endl;
            learn2.Learn2();
            }
    }
```

This is the second .cpp file:

```
#include "Learn1.h"

Learn2::Learn2(){
    cout << "hi" << endl;
}
```

And here is my header file(.h file):

```
 * Learn1.h
 *
 *  Created on: Nov 19, 2016
 *      Author: jacob
 */

#ifndef LEARN1_H_
#define LEARN1_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

class Learn1 {
public:
    Learn1();
    virtual ~Learn1();
};

void showMenu();

class Learn2 {
public:
    Learn2();
};

#endif /* LEARN1_H_ */
```

Yes, I know, the code is a bit random, just keep in mind that I was just poking around with the idea.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the code in line `learn2.Learn2();` ? That is not a valid function call.

Comment: @RSahu I am trying to call the function  Learn2()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a class named `Learn2`, all functions named `Learn2` are constructors. They can be used only to construct objects, not to be called as member functions on objects of the class.

Hence,

```
learn2.Learn2();
```

is wrong.

You can use

```
learn2 = Learn2();
```

to construct a brand new object and then assign it to `learn2`.

If the class had other member functions, you could call them on `learn2.`

```
class Learn2 {
  public:
    Learn2();
    display() { std::cout << "In Learn2::display\n"; }
};

Learn learn2;
learn2.display();
```

Comment: I liked your answer, but it gave me another error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token

Comment: @JakeRamos,  `learn2.display();` cannot be used in global scope. It can be used in a function.

Comment: So it is not possible to call Learn2() from another class?

Comment: @JakeRamos, where did that question come from? I think you should sit down with a good text book to develop a firm understanding of the language. Video tutorials don't seem to good tools to learn the language.

Comment: Ok, let me start over. I made a function in a .cpp file, that I wanted to use in other .cpp file. That function was Learn2(). To do this, I created a class in the header file. I then created a variable for that class in the .cpp file I wanted to use Learn2() in. Then I got the error, and you told me becuase it was a constructor it would not work. So I changed the function name to Learn() so it would not be a constructor, and now i am getting the error: unqualified-id before '.' token

Comment: @JakeRamos, that should work. I can't tell you what's wrong without seeing the code.

Comment: Actually, I fixed that error do just disregard that. I only have one error left however, and it says "multiple definition of Learn2::Learn()"

Comment: @JakeRamos, you should not `#include` .cpp files in other .cpp files. Removing `#include "Learn2.cpp"` should fix that problem.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! I am sorry I was not clear in the beginning, I am completely new to C++. They told me it would be difficult.. haha.

Answer (score 2):

You may not call a class constructor directly. Meaning that this statement is wrong:

```
learn2.Learn2();
```

Comment: So if I am trying to call the function Learn2() from the class Learn2, how should I go about this of that is not the way?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to call the function Learn2() so that it prints "hi". I thought that I was doing that right but apparently not xD.

Comment: The proper way is adding a special method to the class. Something like `Learn2::printHi()`